# Renaming files by adding "cycling" suffix

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

I have a directory containing subdirectories containing many files named as:

```
file1.tif
file2.tif
file3.tif
file4.tif
file5.tif
file6.tif
file7.tif...
```

I want to add a "cycling" suffix `c1`, `c2` and `c3`, to get the file names:

```
file1c1.tif
file2c2.tif
file3c3.tif
file4c1.tif
file5c2.tif
file6c3.tif
file7c1.tif...
```

And this in all subdirectories of the top directory.

But I cannot find out how to do that.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 7):

With `find` + the perl based `prename` (aka `rename` on some earlier Ubuntus) you could match the sequence of digits before a literal `.` and then write it in the desired format using modulo division e.g.

```
find . -name '*.tif' -execdir prename -vn -- 's/(\d+)\./sprintf "%dc%d.", $1, ($1-1)%3+1/e' {} +
```

(the `-vn` flags alllow you to do a 'dry run' to see how the files would be renamed before committing).

---

Ex. given

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── file1.tif
│   ├── file2.tif
│   ├── file3.tif
│   ├── file4.tif
│   ├── file5.tif
│   ├── file6.tif
│   └── file7.tif
├── foo
│   ├── egg
│   │   ├── file1.tif
│   │   └── file2.tif
│   ├── file1.tif
│   ├── file2.tif
│   └── file3.tif
└── spam
    ├── file1.tif
    └── file2.tif

4 directories, 14 files
```

Then

```
find . -name '*.tif' -execdir prename -- 's/(\d+)\./sprintf "%dc%d.", $1, ($1-1)%3+1/e' {} +
```

results in

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── file1c1.tif
│   ├── file2c2.tif
│   ├── file3c3.tif
│   ├── file4c1.tif
│   ├── file5c2.tif
│   ├── file6c3.tif
│   └── file7c1.tif
├── foo
│   ├── egg
│   │   ├── file1c1.tif
│   │   └── file2c2.tif
│   ├── file1c1.tif
│   ├── file2c2.tif
│   └── file3c3.tif
└── spam
    ├── file1c1.tif
    └── file2c2.tif

4 directories, 14 files
```

Answer (score 6):

**Edit based on comment:**

If you want to cycle the counter i.e. `<number>` in `c<number>` to cycle between 1 to 3:

Dry-run:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do 
    ( cd "$d" && pwd && count=1 && shopt -s nullglob && for f in file*.tif; do 
        echo mv -i "$f" "${f%.tif}"c${count}.tif
        if ((count=3)); then 
            count=1
        else
            ((count++))
        fi
     done ) 
done
```

Action:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do 
    ( cd "$d" && count=1 && shopt -s nullglob && for f in file*.tif; do 
        mv -i "$f" "${f%.tif}"c${count}.tif
        if ((count=3)); then 
            count=1
        else
            ((count++))
        fi
     done ) 
done
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── file1.tif
│   ├── file2.tif
│   ├── file3.tif
│   └── file4.tif
├── foo
│   ├── egg
│   │   ├── file1.tif
│   │   └── file2.tif
│   ├── file1.tif
│   ├── file2.tif
│   └── file3.tif
└── spam
    ├── file1.tif
    └── file2.tif

$ shopt -s globstar
$ for d in **/*/; do ( cd "$d" && pwd && count=1 && shopt -s nullglob && for f in file*.tif; do \
    echo mv -i "$f" "${f%.tif}"c${count}.tif; if ((count=3)); then count=1; else ((count++)); fi; done ); done
/home/foobar/bar
mv -i file1.tif file1c1.tif
mv -i file2.tif file2c2.tif
mv -i file3.tif file3c3.tif
mv -i file4.tif file4c1.tif
/home/foobar/foo
mv -i file1.tif file1c1.tif
mv -i file2.tif file2c2.tif
mv -i file3.tif file3c3.tif
/home/foobar/foo/egg
mv -i file1.tif file1c1.tif
mv -i file2.tif file2c2.tif
/home/foobar/spam
mv -i file1.tif file1c1.tif
mv -i file2.tif file2c2.tif

$ for d in **/*/; do ( cd "$d" && count=1 && shopt -s nullglob && for f in file*.tif; do \
    mv -i "$f" "${f%.tif}"c${count}.tif; if ((count=3)); then count=1; else ((count++)); fi; done ); done

$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── file1c1.tif
│   ├── file2c2.tif
│   ├── file3c3.tif
│   └── file4c1.tif
├── foo
│   ├── egg
│   │   ├── file1c1.tif
│   │   └── file2c2.tif
│   ├── file1c1.tif
│   ├── file2c2.tif
│   └── file3c3.tif
└── spam
    ├── file1c1.tif
    └── file2c2.tif
```

---

**Original Answer:**

With `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do ( cd "$d" && pwd && count=1 && shopt -s nullglob \
    && for f in file*.tif; do echo mv -i "$f" "${f%.tif}"c${count}.tif; \
        ((count++)); done ); done
```

- Here we are looping over the directory names, `globstar` shell option lets us to traverse directory recursively
- The part inside `()` runs in a subshell, this is to prevent the `cd` being modified in the current shell
- We are `cd`-ing into the directories, finding the `file*.tif` files and renaming them as needed
- keeping an incrementing counter, `count`, for each file while renaming

---

The above is dry-run, and will show you the directory where the renaming will be done and what `mv` command will be run. If satisfied, do:

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do ( cd "$d" && count=1 && shopt -s nullglob && \
  for f in file*.tif; do mv -i "$f" "${f%.tif}"c${count}.tif; ((count++)); done ); done
```

---

There is a caveat, that as shell does lexical sorting so files e.g. `file10.tif` will be renamed earlier than `file2.tif`. If you don't want that, do some sorting before renaming or use `zsh` with `numericglobsort` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot, heemayl! It would have taken me weeks to write that... There is still something not right, though: the c1, c2... do not "cycle": I get (as well as you in your example "bar" directory): file1c1, file2c2, file3c3, file4c4, file5c5... not: file1c1, file2c2, file3c3, file4c1, file5c2...

Comment: @PhilippeP Meaning after 3 files you want to set the counter to 1 again?

Comment: @PhilippeP Check my edits..

Comment: Yes, great and thanks! That's the loop I needed!               One last question: when I run your script from the master folder of interest, I do get (not always, and I don't understand why...) this message:             mv: cannot stat 'file*.tif': No such file or directory           Your dry-run shows that the directories are correctly found: .../hypoxia-individual/A1
mv -i file*.tif file*c1.tif 
.../hypoxia-individual/A2   ...and so on...         What do I do wrong?

Comment: @PhilippeP Ahhh, forgot about that, thats when no match is found, the glob pattern would  be treated literally then, you need `nullglob`..fixed.

Comment: No more message with your last modification. Dry run shows subdirectories: .../Plate_Individual_images_hypoxia/A1
.../Plate_Individual_images_hypoxia/A2 ...and so on, but unfortunately, "Action" does not modify the contained files names at all :-(

Comment: @PhilippeP working fine for me.. I have only matched files starting with `file` and end in `.tif` by `file*.tif`. Change the pattern if you have different names..

Comment: Really sorry for being slow/heavy... I ran your code, here between bracket: [shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do ( cd "$d" && count=1 && shopt -s nullglob && for f in file*.tif; do \
    mv -i "$f" "${f%.tif}"c${count}.tif; if ((count=3)); then count=1; else ((count++)); fi; done ); done] All my files do get "suffixed", but with "c1", not with a cycling c1, c2, c3. The count loop increment does work for me... ?!

Comment: @PhilippeP `((count=3))`should work. Which version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: Bash version on my system is: GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to heemayl, everything got sorted out. We had to modify the indicated cycle-increment loop a bit, since it did not work in our hands. We changed:
if ((count=3))
into:
if (("$count"==3))
The final code we are now successfully using is:

```
    shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do 
    ( cd "$d" && count=1 && shopt -s nullglob && for f in *.tif; do 
       echo mv -i "$f" "${f%.tif}"c${count}.tif

if (("$count"==3)); then 
count=1
        else 
((count++))
        fi
     done ) 
done
```

Thanks again to heemayl for his/her help and patience...